# TypeScript "Not a constructor function type" error after casting

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
class ClassA {
  field1: any;
}

const SomeClassAsA = diContainer.get('SomeClass') as ClassA;

class ClassB extends ClassA {} // works
class ClassB extends SomeClassAsA {} // error: Type ClassA is not a constructor function type
```

Why can ClassB be extended with ClassA but not with some other Object casted as ClassA? In need to extend SomeClass. How can I accomplish that?

I use TypeScript 1.5.3

Comment: `ClassA` is a class. `SomeClassAsA` is a constant with type `ClassA`

Comment: Okay, that makes kind of sense. Now I know the WHY. But HOW do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const SomeClassAsA = diContainer.get('SomeClass') as typeof ClassA;
//                                                   ^ added
```

When you use a class as a type, you are actually typing an instance of that class. Remember, that a class is a real object in javascript, not like an `interface` which has no raw javascript corollary.

This makes sense, because it allows you to write:

```
const person: Person = new Person()
```

`person` is clearly and an instance of `Person` and not the class constructor object `Person`.

So to get the the type of the class itself, use the `typeof` operator.

[Working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=46#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgSwMLigQwWApgJxgXhgG8AoGcmAcyygAo0dKAuGaHTSgShbTAE9iZCsJw0ArjjDEAvkPKzZJYABs0ECDCSr1AQUHkAZgizK4ARh78A3CUWhIsAMogAtli1qIOrwXjJUGNg4AHTUdADkzm4e6uGcMGowUHwADlggBpraXjZK2VmeAEIwWAAeUFhgcBoxPkTSMAD0jTAA7iA4ANYQeZ4F6kgl5ZXVMFHu2d569U0t7V0QQA)